# Sigbus on std::map.find

Tags: c++, stl

I have got a map defined inside a class in header file like this:

`std::map<int, char> mCompletedIds;`

I can do with a vector here, as I just need to store the ids which have been completed. But to have fast find, I am using map. So, I always put second argument of pair as 0.

Now, In one of the fns. of class, I am doing find.

`std::map<int, char>::iterator it = mCompletedIds.find(id); //id is defined above`

On this statement, I am getting SIGBUS. Is it because map is empty at the moment? Can anyone pls. help me understand the reason.

Thanks,
sg

Comment: It's definitely not from the map being empty; that would just hand back end().  This looks like a memory corruption issue elsewhere manifesting as a bug here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a store of numbers you can use `std::set<int>`

To see if a value is present use

```
std::set<int> mCompletedIds;
bool found = mCompletedIds.count(id) != 0;
```

Your SIGBUS error will usually be caused by bad alignment or some other corruption that happened in your code, and a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) may indicate to you where your real error is.

Comment: Hi, I tried using set. But the error is same. I tried running it with valgrind and that shows no problems, runs successfully, no leaks or any other problems. Also, as soon as I remove find statement, app works fine. I tried running it in gdb, but not much help. On my app console, I am getting this error: Fixing up unaligned userspace access in "App Name" pid=129
6 pc=0x004ecb40 ins=0x6111                                                      
                                                           
Sending SIGBUS to "App Name" due to unaligned access (PC 4
ecb40 PR 50afce)

Answer (score 1):

`std::set` is what you need : [cppRef](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/)

```
int id = 0;

std::set<int> idList;
std::set<int>::iterator it = idList.find(id); //see also count function
if (it != idList.end()) { // find will return set::end if the element is not found
    // id is in your list
} else {
    // id isn't in your list
}
```